# I am trying to update entire column using three column form same table. But it is showing error

Tags: mysql

```
update tr_lastyear 
set DocDate = (select STR_TO_DATE(concat(TR_yyyy, '/', TR_mm, '/', TR_dd), '%Y/%m/%d') from tr_lastyear);
```

main table

[image]

Comment: Rather odd you would jump through all those loops when `set DocDate = concat(TR_yyyy, '-', TR_mm, '-', TR_dd)` is all you really need

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to select

```
update tr_lastyear 
 set DocDate =  STR_TO_DATE(concat(TR_yyyy, '/', TR_mm, '/', TR_dd), '%Y/%m/%d');
```

since there is not where all rows will be updated.

Comment: it is showing error

Comment: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: Error is clear enough , you could add where 1 = 1 if you don't want to toggle safe mode

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked. i uncheked the safe mode.